# Solr not returning any results on partial or exact value input

Tags: input, solr

So i have been trying to solve this problem now for 2 days and i am no closer to a solution than when i began. I am trying to retreive results from Solr based on incomplete user input, example:

I have a product name `Large red table`
I type in `table` in the q parameter and expect Solr to return (among other results) `Large red table`, but i get no results.

I know the item exists as i can get all documents using `*:*` in the q parameter to get all results. Schema.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="*****" version="1.5">

   <!-- Standard Fields -->
   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<!--
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
-->

   <!--Custom Fields--> 
   <field name="ProductName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="ProductLongDescription" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="ProductID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="false" /> <!-- varcher -->
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>



   <!--FieldTypes-->

   <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyser type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyser>

      <analyser type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyser>

   </fieldType>


   <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

   <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
   </fieldType>

   <!-- Copyfields -->
   <copyField source="ProductName" dest="text" />
   <copyField source="ProductLongDescription" dest="text" />

   <!-- Dynamicfields -->

   <!-- Unique key -->
   <!--
   <uniqueKey>ProductID</uniqueKey>
-->

</schema>
```

So "text" is defined, and points to ProductName and ProductLongDescription through copyFields. /select handler looks like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>      
       <str name="df">text</str>        
     </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

If i put `ProductName:*` in the q parameter it finds all product names, but if i use patial input like `ProductName:table` or even exact matching values like `ProductName:Large red table` i get no results.

I have tried using edismax, different tokenizers and filters but nothing works. Can anybody tell why this is not working? I looked at the example-DIH code that came with the program and have tried to copy it as much as i can, as that example works with only partial input on the q parameter.

Comment: And you've reindexed after each change to schema.xml? And what does the analysis page show when you enter "Large red table" for the indexed value and "large" as the query value for the ProductName field?

Comment: First off, thank you for the quick reply. Yes i reindexed with every change, but i think i may have solved this issue myself whithin the time it took you to reply. Im 90% sure now that the issue was the field type in my schema. I was using the text_general one, but when i tried the analyser relevant to the language on the data source, i got results from partial input.